# Pass content as object in angular-strap popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to do the following:

I have a json array of questions which I pass like this:

```
<a href=""
  ...
  title="Questions"
  data-content="{{item.questions}}"
  data-template="popover.question.tpl.html"
  ...
  bs-popover>
    {{item.questions.length}}
</a>
```

and a template 'popover.question.tpl.html' that  contains the following code:

```
<div class="popover">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h3 class="popover-title" ng-bind="title" ng-show="title"></h3>
  <div class="popover-content" ng-model="content">
  <ul>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="question in content">
      {{question.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is probably that the content is passed as a string by the directive, leading in the ng-repeat not working. If I just evaluate "{{content}}" I get the actual json data in my div but obviously I can't work with that. Any ideas on how to do that? Do I *have* to create a separate controller for that (which I would like to avoid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data-content will accept only string. So object cannot be passed through that.
Angular-strap popover will inherit the scope from where it is getting opened.

So, in your popover.question.tpl.html you can directly access item.questions.

```
<div class="popover">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h3 class="popover-title" ng-bind="title" ng-show="title"></h3>
  <div class="popover-content" ng-model="content">
  <ul>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="question in item.questions">
      {{question.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zN5d6lvjpBLC1BUSvbB0?p=preview) for working example.

Comment: Thanks! As I was using this inside a grid (trNgGrid to be exact) I was not sure about the scope being inherited, and didn't bother to try it :-))